# Cannot run tests when legacy connection is unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord

I have a secondary connection to a legacy system in an abstract ActiveRecord model, which I use just to query an external SQL server database.

Since I don't have access to this connection all the time, I was hoping that I could just skip or use mocks on the tests that involved that connection when it was not available. However, when I try to run any test the fixture loading mechanism tries to establish the secondary connection, and if it's not available it throws an "Unable to open socket" or "Unable to connect" exception, which means that I cannot run my test suite offline.

Any suggestions that don't involve disabling fixtures are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Webmock https://github.com/bblimke/webmock and VCR https://github.com/vcr/vcr ?

;)